# How do get a value data of key in json file

Tags: python

I have a json file from url and I want to get a value of key 'OnePie_KEY' in json that.

```
    import requests
    hosturl = requests.get(url='http://api.jsoneditoronline.org/v1/docs/abf48114b71a43f380cd114d37a4bb9d')
    print(hosturl.json(['OnePie_KEY']))
```

But it not work

My Json from URL

```
{"name":"Kisame","schema":{"type":"NONE","url":null,"id":null,"content":null,"leftPanel":false,"rightPanel":false},"updated":"2021-09-19T16:47:45.419Z","_rev":33,"_id":"abf48114b71a43f380cd114d37a4bb9d","data":"{\n  \"HWID\": {\n    \"000001\": [\n      \"Riici\",\n      \"xx399\",\n      \"\",\n      1\n    ]\n  },\n  \"OnePie_KEY\": \"112233445566778899\",\n  \"MD5\": \"121321312514654665\"\n}"}
```

I wanto read value in key "OnePie_KEY", many thanks for help

Comment: The URI response is not a json but an HTML file, so `json` function should not work.

Comment: That url does not respond with JSON. Try *print(hosturl.text)* to see what you actually get and go from there

Comment: Try `print(hosturl.json()['OnePie_KEY'])`

Comment: I guess OP just wants to show JSON they get. Please, post the JSON here in the question and show your actual code, however I expect @Frank suggestion will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two lines of your code work fine:

```
import requests
hosturl = requests.get(url='http://api.jsoneditoronline.org/v1/docs/abf48114b71a43f380cd114d37a4bb9d')
```

Your `hosturl` variable now contains lots of useful information.

```
print(hosturl)
# Prints "<Response [200]>" telling us the request was successful

print(hosturl.text)
# Renders the body of the response as text: '{"name":"Kisame","schema":{"t...
```

There is also the `.json()` method which will read the `.text` attribute as JSON in effect converting it to Python dicts and lists

```
json_response = hosturl.json()

print(json_response.keys())
# Prints the following keys:
# dict_keys(['name', 'schema', 'updated', '_rev', '_id', 'data'])
```

Inspecting the ['data'] key we see that its contents is still a string and not an object

```
print(json_response['data'])
# '{\n  "HWID": {\n    "000001": [\n      "Riici",\n      "xx399",\n      "",\n      1\n    ]\n  },\n  "OnePie_KEY": "112233445566778899",\n  "MD5": "121321312514654665"\n}'
```

We use the `loads()` (load string) method in the `json` module to convert this string:

```
import json

data = json.loads(json_response['data'])

print(data)
# {'HWID': {'000001': ['Riici', 'xx399', '', 1]}, 'OnePie_KEY': '112233445566778899', 'MD5': '121321312514654665'}
# Notice no newline characters or quotes around the {}    

print(data.keys())
# dict_keys(['HWID', 'OnePie_KEY', 'MD5'])

print(data['OnePie_KEY'])
# 112233445566778899
```

Comment: Thank @Frank very much, the instructions are very detailed and easy to understand - I am a non-English speaker, hope to understand